# Python del sys.modules triggered issues

Tags: python, sys

## mod.py

```
print "this is mod modules ..."
import sys
del sys.modules['mod']
sys.modules['mod'] = "test mod"
```

## main.py

```
import mod

print mod
```

when I execute, display exception:

```
# python main.py
this is mod modules ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mod
  File "/root/test1111/mod.py", line 4, in <module>
    sys.modules['mod'] = "test mod"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

I want to know, excuse me, what caused this?

Comment: The Python import process is a fairly complicated mechanism and you shouldn't interfere with it unless you know precisely what you are doing. I think you should explain why you think it is necessary to delete entries in `sys.modules`. There is probably a less drastic way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Keep in mind that `sys` itself is a global name in the module you just deleted.

Comment: (I'm kind of surprised it's an `AttributeError`, not a `NameError`, that you get.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete stuff in sys.modules. It is internally used by the interpreter and undefined behavior might occur when you delete it, especially if you try to reimport a module a second time.

Undefined behavior means weird errors can crop up, the interpreter can crash or your cat could catch on fire.